# How can I create a UIView at a certain CGPoint?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgpoint

I need to be able to create and display a UIView at a a certain CGPoint.

So far I have a gesture recogniser that is added as a subview to the main view.

I then create a UIView programatically and set's it's x and y coordinates to the CGPoint that I got from the gesture recogniser.

I am able to create it and add it as a subview but the position of the created UIView is different from the location of the TAP.

AnimationView subclasses UIView

My code is below

```
    tappedLocation = gesture.locationInView(self.view)

    var animationImage: AnimationView = AnimationView()
    animationImage.frame = CGRectMake(tappedLocation.x, tappedLocation.y, 64, 64)
    animationImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.view.addSubview(animationImage)
    animationImage.addFadeAnimation(removedOnCompletion: true)
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with different? Completely another position or near by?

Comment: It turns out that after closer inspection it creates the view with the left corner at the position of the tap. I guess that is the x + y coordinates of the tap. How do I make the view spawn directly in the centre of the tap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is, that the you want that the center of the view is the point you clicked. At the moment the top left corner of your `UIView` will be the point you touched. So try that:

```
 var frameSize:CGFloat = 64
 animationImage.frame = CGRectMake(tappedLocation.x - frameSize/2, tappedLocation.y - frameSize/2, frameSize, frameSize)
```

As you see, Now you set the width and height before and adjust the x and y so that the center of your view is the point you touched.

But a better way is, like Rob mentioned in his answer to just set the center of the view to your location. That way you only have to set the size of your frame and use the `CGSizeMake` instead the `CGRectMake` method:

```
animationImage.frame.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
animationImage.center = tappedLocation
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set its `center`:

```
animationImage.center = tappedLocation
```

Comment: Didn't know about that. Much better way than just using calculating the middle point.  +1

Answer (score -1):

Let's create a Tap Gesture and assign it to a View

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: "tappedView:") // action is the call to the function that will be executed every time a Tap gesture gets recognised.
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Every time you tap a view with the assigned Tap Gesture, this function gets called.

```
func tappedView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
// Now you ca access all the UITapGestureRecognizer API and play with it however you want.

    // You want to center your view to the location of the Tap.
    myView.center = sender.view!.center

}
```